# How to query the forwarded record count for a temp table created by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

May have some overhead with forwarded records for a temp table created / populated / queried by a stored proc.

How do you query the forwarded record count for a temp table created / used by a stored proc?

I want to get the forwarded record count from inside the procedure.

Comment: From inside the proc, or from the outside world? From outside might be difficult due to the temporary nature of a temp table. :-)

Comment: Oops, from inside the proc... Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the same method as you would from a normal table. Just keep in mind that the temp table lives in tempdb. I.e., use the `OBJECT_ID()` function to get the ID of your temp table and qualify the database name for your temp table with tempdb, as in:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTemp')
```

Here's a full example:

```
USE Adventureworks
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC p
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #myTemp (c1 int identity, filler varchar(200))

--Populate the temp table
INSERT INTO #myTemp (filler) SELECT TOP(10000) 'a' FROM sys.all_columns AS a, sys.all_columns AS b

--Generate some fwd records
UPDATE #myTemp SET filler = REPLICATE('s', 190) WHERE c1 % 2 = 1

--Fyi, get the ID of a temp table
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTemp') AS id_of_the_temptable

--Get the forwarded record count for our table table
SELECT forwarded_record_count FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('tempdb'), OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTemp'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
GO

--Run the proc
EXEC p
```